# Copy background jobs and installed softwares to AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I have some installed software like node and some background cron jobs running on my EC2 instance. Now when I create a AMI I want all these configurations to be copied to the AMI. Do I have to write some script for the same or the AMI creation will take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMI creation will copy installed software and cron config files as it is based on a snapshot of the disk

The only thing to check is that the configuration that individual packages have is not somehow tied to the specific IP or subnet of the instances that it was originally installed on